# Compare time from MS access database with current system time

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Good day! I am a beginner at using MS access and visual basic. Currently I am having a hard time comparing the time from my database with the current system time. I have a database wherein there is a schedule, the schedule will be compared with the current system time. if fifteen minutes have passed, a message will appear on the computer screen that someone has not yet logged in. the following is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim date1 As Date
        Dim date2 As Date = Date.Now
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cnn.Open()
        End If
        Dim myDate As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT DT FROM Test", cnn)
        cnn.Close()
    End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database121.accdb"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any response will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` connections allow us to use both the `DateDiff()` and `Now()` functions in Access SQL queries, so you could use something like the following (in C#, but VB.NET would be very similar):

```csharp
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = 
            @"SELECT DateDiff(""n"",[LastLogin],Now()) AS mins " +
            @"FROM [Clients] WHERE [ID]=1";
    int mins = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Last login was {0} minute(s) ago.", mins));
}
```

For more information on the `DateDiff()` function, see the following page from the Office online documentation

[DateDiff Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/datediff-function-HA001228811.aspx)